# Why does GCC 3.x optimize for size sufficiently but GCC 4.x does not for this code?

Tags: gcc, boot, bootloader

https://github.com/bford/PIOS/tree/lab1/boot

That is part of the repository for a microkernel used in the Yale operating systems course. I'm not in that course - this isn't a homework question. This is a question that stemmed from curiosity upon observing someone else in a totally different university trying out the coursework for giggles...

Apparently, compiling that code in GCC 4.x results in an executable larger than a sector (512 bytes) and therefore unsuitable for acting as a bootloader. Compiling it in GCC 3.x results in something <500 bytes in size. Optimization flags used were identical, and may be seen in the Makefiles located in that repository.

**My question is:** what in the world changed between GCC 3.x codegen and GCC 4.x codegen that could have possibly caused that 'regression'?

Answer (score 0):

It is not uncommon for gcc to gain new optimization options between major versions. Some of them may be on by default in any of the `-O[123]` levels and they might optimize for speed instead of size.

It is hard to give a specific answer without knowing the actual options you use to compile.

Comment: They're all there in the makefile linked. -O0 is the primary flag of interest, and was present in all compiles. No other relevant -f flags (afaik from the makefiles) were used. Ld was passed flags to strip extraneous symbols.